# How to check if data exists at a certain Pandas index?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with month as the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Jan', 'Apr', 'July', 'Oct'],
                   'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
                    'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})
df.set_index('month',inplace=True)

print(df)

       year  sale
month            
Jan    2012    55
Apr    2014    40
July   2013    84
Oct    2014    31
```

And I have a function that does something if there is data for a particular month. Let's look for June (it's not in the DF)

```
# if there is June data:
if df.loc['June']:

    print('June Data Exists')
```

However I get the error obviously because there is no June data:

```
KeyError: 'June'
```

I did a `try except`, but I am just wondering of there is a better method/ some kind of one liner Like:

```
if this exists:
 do that
```

My try except workaround:

```
try:
    # if there is June data:
    if df.loc['June']:

        print('June Data Exists')

except:

    print('No June data available')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pure python solution with `in`:

```
if 'June' in df.index:
    print('June Data Exists')
else:
    print('No June data available')
```

Or compare all values and test by `any` - at least one `True`:

```
if (df.index == 'June').any():
    print('June Data Exists')
else:
    print('No June data available')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with isin() method

```
if df.index.isin(['June']).any():
  print('June data exists')
else:
  print('June data does not exists')
```

if there are multiple choices that you want to validate,,do the following way

```
   if df.index.isin(['June','Dec']).any():
      print('data exists')
    else:
      print('data does not exists')
```